# WKInterfacePicker Caption

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

Do you know how to add static caption to the watchOS picker? The caption looks like this and it says *Item 1.*

[image: Black square with Apple Watch picker deploying colours: Red, Green, highlighted in green with bright green caption on top which says item 1]

I already selected appropriate style in the Interface Builder:

[image: Displays macOS drop down menu with 3 options. Outline with caption is selected.]

My code:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    let item1 = WKPickerItem()
    item1.title = "10"
    let item2 = WKPickerItem()
    item2.title = "20"
    let item3 = WKPickerItem()
    item3.title = "30"
    picker.setItems([item1, item2, item3])

    picker.focus()
}
```

Result I got in the Simulator:

[image: Apple Watch screenshot with the picker and 2 buttons. Picker also outlined in green but doesn't have any caption on top.]

How to add missing caption on top of the picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide a caption to each `WKPickerItem`:

```
let item1 = WKPickerItem()
item1.title = "10"
item1.caption = "CAPTION!"
```